# Updating GitExtensions on Windows XP with .NET 4.0 gets error '...4.0 must be installed...'

Tags: .net, windows, git, windows-xp, git-extensions

I am trying to update and/or install the GitExtensions240SetupComplete.msi with an error of

```
.NET Framework 4.0 must be installed prior to installation of Git Extensions
```

I happen to have all updates and my most recent .NET is v4.0.30319. I can install GitExtensions233SetupComplete.msi with no issues, so it is possible to stick with this version. I just want to make sure there is not something I can do to get the newest version and if worth the update.

Comment: I can only say I'm in the same situation but my update went trough with no issues at all. Maybe you have several NET installation and 4 isn't the default? It's certainly something you can fix in your end tho.

Comment: @Cawas Unfortunately this is on a company computer with a lot of features overriding standard access to admin. I am not familiar with having multiple .NET installations but I will check with the IT department.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue with Windows 7 x64 with .net v4.0.30319 already installed.

Comment: @AlanMacdonald my IT guy said it might be picking up the older .NET versions, but not to erase as those might be fall-backs for older software.

Comment: @Shane thanks for getting back to me.  I just so happened to install Visual Studio 2012 last night and after that the GitExtensions setup worked!  Maybe the error message is wrong and it really means .Net 4.5.  Or maybe some other dependency got installed with VS2012 that GitExtensions needs.